# Subset a special case in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which contains multiple numeric columns

```
x = 
a b c d
1 2 3 2
2 3 5 1
1 3 4 6
. . . .
. . . .
```

another list i have where some rules are defined in terms of range for each variable

```
y = 
y[[1]]
y[[1]][[1]]
1
2
y[[1]][[2]]
5
6
y[[2]]
y[[2]][[1]]
2
3
y[[3]]
y[[3]][[1]]
5
6
y[[3]][[2]]
8
9
y[[3]][[3]]
10
11
y[[4]]    
y[[4]][[1]]
12
15
```

I want to create all possible data frames when each combination of variables is taken say:

```
dataframe1 = variable 1 is from 1:2,
variable 2 is from 2:3, 
variable 3 is from 5:6 and 
variable 4 is from 12:15 is one data frame

dataframe2 = variable 1 is from 5:6, 
variable 2 is from 2:3, 
variable 3 i from 5:6 and 
variable 4 is from 12:15 is one data frame
```

and so on...

sample data

```
structure(list(c(2441.321994, 2441.295962, 2441.269929, 2441.243897, 
2441.217865, 2441.191832, 2441.1658, 2441.139767, 2441.113735, 
2441.087702, 2441.06167, 2441.035637, 2441.009605, 2440.983572, 
2440.95754, 2440.931507, 2440.905475, 2440.879443, 2440.85341, 
2440.827378), c(998.6875404, 998.6989679, 998.7103955, 998.721823, 
998.7332505, 998.744678, 998.7561055, 998.767533, 998.7789605, 
998.7903881, 998.8018156, 998.8132431, 998.8246706, 998.8360981, 
998.8475256, 998.8589531, 998.8703806, 998.8818082, 998.8932357, 
998.9046632), c(4272184.479, 4272207.767, 4272231.055, 4272254.344, 
4272277.632, 4272300.92, 4272324.209, 4272347.497, 4272370.786, 
4272394.074, 4272417.362, 4272440.651, 4272463.939, 4272487.227, 
4272510.516, 4272533.804, 4272557.093, 4272580.381, 4272603.669, 
4272626.958), c(560.8931785, 562.3330729, 563.0583984, 562.3908637, 
563.3387891, 562.7498197, 561.9703322, 561.9606988, 563.5061892, 
563.2322049, 562.7148307, 561.6984375, 561.3954731, 560.8977865, 
560.8382398, 562.8975675, 563.9937645, 563.540068, 562.5878996, 
561.2869919)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

sample list

```
list(list(c(2400, 2430), c(2435, 2530), c(2600,2700)), list(c(900, 950), c(960,1000)), list(c(4272184,4272417)), list(c(560,561), c(562:563)))
```

Desired output is 2 data frames in this example where:

```
DF1 = var1 between 2400 2430, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF2 = var1 between 2435 2530, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF3 = var1 between 2600 2700, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF4 = var1 between 2400 2430, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF5 = var1 between 2435 2530, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF6 = var1 between 2600 2700, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 560 561
DF7 = var1 between 2400 2430, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
DF8 = var1 between 2435 2530, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
DF9 = var1 between 2600 2700, var2 between 900 950, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
DF10 = var1 between 2400 2430, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
DF11 = var1 between 2435 2530, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
DF12 = var1 between 2600 2700, var2 between 960 1000, var3 between 4272184 4272417, var4 between 562 563
```

Comment: Please provide your data and list in a form we can work with, e.g. by using `dput()`.

Comment: show some of the desired output data.frames.

Comment: uploaded sample data
will provide sample list too

Comment: given the feel of real data in the question now

Comment: thanks for your interest in the problem

Comment: @RahulKumarVij It is not clear why for your dataframe2 variable 3 has a range 5:6, not 8:9. Also Do you always have only 2 dataframes? Are there cases when there are 3 or more dataframes?

Comment: dataframes can be any number

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
# load the package
library(data.table)

# create a reference data.table from the list
ref <- as.data.table(lapply(l, unlist))[, grp := rowid(V2)
                                        ][, dcast(.SD, grp ~ rowid(grp),
                                                  value.var = c('V1','V2'))]


# convert 'df' to a data.table
setDT(df)

# use the join capability of data.table to add a grouping variable
# from 'ref' to those rows that fit the criteria
df[, grp := ref[.SD
                , on = .(V1_1 < var1, V1_2 > var1, V2_1 < var2, V2_2 > var2)
                , grp]]


# filter out the rows where no grp was assigned
df2 <- df[!is.na(grp)]

# split the result
split(df2, df2$grp)
```

which gives:

> ```
> $`1`
>         var1     var2    var3     var4 grp
>  1: 2421.322 948.6875 4272184 560.8932   1
>  2: 2421.270 948.7104 4272231 563.0584   1
>  3: 2421.218 948.7333 4272278 563.3388   1
>  4: 2421.166 948.7561 4272324 561.9703   1
>  5: 2421.114 948.7790 4272371 563.5062   1
>  6: 2421.062 948.8018 4272417 562.7148   1
>  7: 2421.010 948.8247 4272464 561.3955   1
>  8: 2420.958 948.8475 4272511 560.8382   1
>  9: 2420.905 948.8704 4272557 563.9938   1
> 10: 2420.853 948.8932 4272604 562.5879   1
>
> $`2`
>         var1     var2    var3     var4 grp
>  1: 2441.322 998.6875 4272184 560.8932   2
>  2: 2441.296 998.6990 4272208 562.3331   2
>  3: 2441.270 998.7104 4272231 563.0584   2
>  4: 2441.244 998.7218 4272254 562.3909   2
>  5: 2441.218 998.7333 4272278 563.3388   2
>  6: 2441.192 998.7447 4272301 562.7498   2
>  7: 2441.166 998.7561 4272324 561.9703   2
>  8: 2441.140 998.7675 4272347 561.9607   2
>  9: 2441.114 998.7790 4272371 563.5062   2
> 10: 2441.088 998.7904 4272394 563.2322   2
> 11: 2441.062 998.8018 4272417 562.7148   2
> 12: 2441.036 998.8132 4272441 561.6984   2
> 13: 2441.010 998.8247 4272464 561.3955   2
> 14: 2440.984 998.8361 4272487 560.8978   2
> 15: 2440.958 998.8475 4272511 560.8382   2
> 16: 2440.932 998.8590 4272534 562.8976   2
> 17: 2440.905 998.8704 4272557 563.9938   2
> 18: 2440.879 998.8818 4272580 563.5401   2
> 19: 2440.853 998.8932 4272604 562.5879   2
> 20: 2440.827 998.9047 4272627 561.2870   2
> ```

With the `list2env`-function you can break up the list and put the datatables in the Global environment if you want.

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(2421.321994, 2421.295962, 2421.269929, 2421.243897, 2421.217865, 2421.191832, 2421.1658, 2421.139767, 2421.113735, 2421.087702, 2421.06167, 2421.035637, 2421.009605, 2420.983572, 2420.95754, 2420.931507, 2420.905475, 2420.879443, 2420.85341, 2420.827378, 2441.321994, 2441.295962, 2441.269929, 2441.243897, 2441.217865, 2441.191832, 2441.1658, 2441.139767, 2441.113735, 2441.087702, 2441.06167, 2441.035637, 2441.009605, 2440.983572, 2440.95754, 2440.931507, 2440.905475, 2440.879443, 2440.85341, 2440.827378, 2461.321994, 2461.295962, 2461.269929, 2461.243897, 2461.217865, 2461.191832, 2461.1658, 2461.139767, 2461.113735, 2461.087702, 2461.06167, 2461.035637, 2461.009605, 2460.983572, 2460.95754, 2460.931507, 2460.905475, 2460.879443, 2460.85341, 2460.827378),
                     var2 = c(948.6875404, 898.6989679, 948.7103955, 898.721823, 948.7332505, 898.744678, 948.7561055, 898.767533, 948.7789605, 898.7903881, 948.8018156, 898.8132431, 948.8246706, 898.8360981, 948.8475256, 898.8589531, 948.8703806, 898.8818082, 948.8932357, 898.9046632, 998.6875404, 998.6989679, 998.7103955, 998.721823, 998.7332505, 998.744678, 998.7561055, 998.767533, 998.7789605, 998.7903881, 998.8018156, 998.8132431, 998.8246706, 998.8360981, 998.8475256, 998.8589531, 998.8703806, 998.8818082, 998.8932357, 998.9046632, 1048.6875404, 1098.6989679, 1048.7103955, 1098.721823, 1048.7332505, 1098.744678, 1048.7561055, 1098.767533, 1048.7789605, 1098.7903881, 1048.8018156, 1098.8132431, 1048.8246706, 1098.8360981, 1048.8475256, 1098.8589531, 1048.8703806, 1098.8818082, 1048.8932357, 1098.9046632),
                     var3 = c(4272184.479, 4272207.767, 4272231.055, 4272254.344, 4272277.632, 4272300.92, 4272324.209, 4272347.497, 4272370.786, 4272394.074, 4272417.362, 4272440.651, 4272463.939, 4272487.227, 4272510.516, 4272533.804, 4272557.093, 4272580.381, 4272603.669, 4272626.958, 4272184.479, 4272207.767, 4272231.055, 4272254.344, 4272277.632, 4272300.92, 4272324.209, 4272347.497, 4272370.786, 4272394.074, 4272417.362, 4272440.651, 4272463.939, 4272487.227, 4272510.516, 4272533.804, 4272557.093, 4272580.381, 4272603.669, 4272626.958, 4272184.479, 4272207.767, 4272231.055, 4272254.344, 4272277.632, 4272300.92, 4272324.209, 4272347.497, 4272370.786, 4272394.074, 4272417.362, 4272440.651, 4272463.939, 4272487.227, 4272510.516, 4272533.804, 4272557.093, 4272580.381, 4272603.669, 4272626.958),
                     var4 = c(560.8931785, 562.3330729, 563.0583984, 562.3908637, 563.3387891, 562.7498197, 561.9703322, 561.9606988, 563.5061892, 563.2322049, 562.7148307, 561.6984375, 561.3954731, 560.8977865, 560.8382398, 562.8975675, 563.9937645, 563.540068, 562.5878996, 561.2869919, 560.8931785, 562.3330729, 563.0583984, 562.3908637, 563.3387891, 562.7498197, 561.9703322, 561.9606988, 563.5061892, 563.2322049, 562.7148307, 561.6984375, 561.3954731, 560.8977865, 560.8382398, 562.8975675, 563.9937645, 563.540068, 562.5878996, 561.2869919, 560.8931785, 562.3330729, 563.0583984, 562.3908637, 563.3387891, 562.7498197, 561.9703322, 561.9606988, 563.5061892, 563.2322049, 562.7148307, 561.6984375, 561.3954731, 560.8977865, 560.8382398, 562.8975675, 563.9937645, 563.540068, 562.5878996, 561.2869919)),
                .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")

l <- list(list(c(2400, 2430), c(2435, 2530)), c(900, 1000))
```

`df` was constructed OP's original dat as follows:

```
names(df) <- paste0('var', seq_along(df))
df <- rbind(df - list(20, c(50,100), 0, 0), df, df + list(20, c(50,100), 0, 0))
```

Comment: ref <- as.data.table(lapply(l, unlist))[, grp := rowid(V2)
                                        ][, dcast(.SD, grp ~ rowid(grp),
                                                  value.var = c('V1','V2'))]
this function creates works for 2 variables only and create a limited grps

Comment: but thanks for this
which will definitely help me to identify the direction

Comment: @RahulKumarVij If you update your example to better match your problem, I can look whether I can help.